# How to apply my css changes only to one component in react js. Css file includes body tag and other tags which are affecting other components as well

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, css-selectors

How to apply my css changes only to one component in react js. Css file includes body tag and other tags which are affecting other components as well. I have added Ids to each element in the required component where this css rules should be appiled. But its not working. Below are the files. I need the css rules to be applied only to the About.jsx component without affecting other components. Thanks in advance.

**About.jsx component**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import LinkedInIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LinkedIn';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import LocalPostOfficeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalPostOffice';
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';
import logo from '../assets/profile-pic.jpeg';
       
const About = () => {                              

    return (
        <body id='about1'>
            <section id='about2'>
                <div className='container' id='about3'>
                    <div className='card' id='about4'>
                        <div className='content' id='about5'>
                            <div className='imgBx' id='about6'>
                                <img src={logo} alt='Logo' id='about7' />
                            </div>
                            <div className='contentBx' id='about8'>
                                <h3 id='about9'>Rishi<br /><span id='about10'>Software Developer</span></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul className='sci' id='about11'>
                            <li style={{ '--i': '1' }} id='about12'>
                                <a href='#' id='about13'><LinkedInIcon fontSize='small' sx={{ color: blue[500] }} /></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style={{ '--i': '2' }} id='about14'>
                                <a href='#' id='about15'><TwitterIcon fontSize='small' sx={{ color: blue[500] }} /></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style={{ '--i': '3' }} id='about16'>
                                <a href='#' id='about17'><LocalPostOfficeIcon fontSize='small' sx={{ color: blue[500] }} /></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            </body>
    );
}

export default About;
```

**About.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
*
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body
{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: #161623;
min-height: 100vh;
}
section::before
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(#f00,#f0f);
clip-path: circle(30% at right 70%);
}
section::after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(#2196f3,#e91e63);
clip-path: circle(20% at 10% 10%);
}
.container
{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin: 40px 0;
}
.container .card
{
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
margin: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-radius: 15px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
.container .card .content
{
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .content
{
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.container .card .content .imgBx
{
position: relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.container .card .content .imgBx img
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
.container .card .content .contentBx h3
{
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
margin: 20px 0 10px;
line-height: 1.1em;
}
.container .card .content .contentBx h3 span
{
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: initial;
}
.container .card .sci
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
display: flex;
}
.container .card .sci li
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0 10px;
transform: translateY(40px);
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 0;
}
.container .card:hover .sci li
{
transform: translateY(0px);
opacity: 1;
}
.container .card .sci li a
{
color: #fff;
font-size:24px;
}
```

**Other Css and scss files-->**
**File1**

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <HeaderContainer>
        <LogoContainer to='/'>
            <Logo className='logo' />
        </LogoContainer>            
        <OptionsContainer>                
            <Profile />
            </OptionsContainer>
        </HeaderContainer>                  
        <HomePageContent />            
    </React.Fragment>
);

    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import { Link as RRDLink } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    export const HeaderContainer = styled.div`
        height: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    `;
    
    export const FooterContainer = styled.div`    
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding:10px;    
        display: block;   
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        margin-top:50px;
    `;
    
    export const LogoContainer = styled(RRDLink)`// this link is a custom component thats why we did like styled(Link)
         height: 100%;
          width: 70px;
          padding: 25px;      
    `;
    
    export const OptionsContainer = styled.div`      
          height: 100%;
          width: 70px;
          padding: 15px;
    `;
    
    export const OptionLink = styled(RRDLink)`
          padding: 10px 10px;
          cursor: pointer;
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
    `;
```

**File2**

```
 const HomePage = () => (
    <HomePageContainer>
        <Directory />
    </HomePageContainer>
    );


import styled from 'styled-components';

export const HomePageContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 80px; 
`;
```

**File3**

```
const Directory = ({ sections }) => (
    <div className='directory-menu'>
        {
            sections.map(({ id, ...otherSectionProps }) => (
                <MenuItem key={id} {...otherSectionProps} />
            ))
        }
    </div>
    );

        .directory-menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
```

**File4**

```
 const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, history, linkUrl, match }) => (
    <div
        className={`${size} menu-item`}
        onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}${linkUrl}`)}
    >

        <div className='background-image' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}></div>
        <div className='content'>
            <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>                
        </div>
    </div>
);

.menu-item {
        min-width: 30%;
        height: 240px;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 0 7.5px 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
    
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
    
            & .background-image {
                transform: scale(1.1);
                transition: transform 6s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.45, 0.45, 0.95);
            }
    
            & .content {
                opacity: 0.9;
            }
        }
    
        &.large {
            height: 380px;
        }
    
        &:first-child {
            margin-right: 7.5px;
        }
    
        &:last-child {
            margin-left: 7.5px;
        }
    
        .background-image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    
        .content {
            height: 90px;
            padding: 0 25px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
            opacity: 0.7;
            position: absolute;
    
            .title {
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: 6px;
                font-size: 22px;
                color: #4a4a4a;
            }
    
            .subtitle {
                font-weight: lighter;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue using styled-components.

Useful link for styled-components--> https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native

Example-> https://codesandbox.io/s/lxm7q494kz?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at "**CSS Modules Stylesheet in react**", here a add some links with some information

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

https://reactgo.com/react-app-css-modules/

Comment: Tried this approach. Not working.